# UIWebView loadRequest VS loadData

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

When I use loadRequest the page fits itself to the screen and looks like a mobile app.
When I use NSURLConnection to load data, and then load it to the webView it looks like the normal site and doesn't fit to the screen.

In both cases I use the same url.

how can I get the second way to give good results like the first one?

Comment: The server is probably returning different content depending on the `user-agent` passed in the request. Since you request is done by the `NSURLConnection` this header is missing. Adding one might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work well and easy:
https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKWebViewProgress

Answer (score 1):

When you make the first way, uiwebview send additional info about device, info media data of sender, then server give back proper content.
As well as it's depends on media parameters are inserted of header html. Make sure that such parameters exist in your data content.
Secondly, such media parameters of type devices is stored into .css files and possibly they are missing in your data content.